# PHP script not writing all the data to JSON-file

Tags: javascript, php, css, json, html

I'm writing JSON data to a file using a php script but for some reason it's not writing all the data.

[Here's the JSON](https://api.myjson.com/bins/2mv53)

and this is the php script.

```
<?php
  $myFile = "json/countries.json";
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
  $stringData = json_encode($_POST["data"]);
  fwrite($fh, $stringData);
  fclose($fh);
?>
```

It's only writing down to Suriname. 
Does anyone know what might be the problem?

It has worked fine but suddently stopped and I've checked the code but can't see any problem other than the PHP-script.

Not a big PHP programmer so thought I'd ask here and hopefully be able to rule that out.

Thanks!

Comment: You provided the JSON, but can you provide the `$_POST['data']` you're using?

Comment: The link is a JSON representation of the data object I'm trying to write to the file.

Comment: Ok then if I paste this as $_POST['data'] it works fine for me..

Comment: Have you done a var_dump() (or equivalent) of $stringData just before the fwrite, and does that definitely contain more info than is written to the file?

Comment: The php script is in a seperate php file so it's not writing to the console. Is there some other way to check or write the var_dump?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that there is no problem with the code. Just sent an AJAX post request on my local server setup (ISS 7.5, PHP 5.6 FAST/CGI) using the JSON string you've provided in the link. I guess on the client side the data is gathered and `JSON.stringify` is performed on the data to get a JSON object.

When it arrives on the server you `json_encode` it. This will result in a double encoded JSON object. Just remove `json_encode` since the data is already formatted correctly as JSON.

Maybe your server somehow truncates the data.